# why does vector return miss some value?

Tags: c++, vector

```
int main(int argc, char argv)
{
    int myarray[] = {1, 2, 3, 5};
    std::vector<int> array(myarray, myarray + 4);
    std::vector<int> *p = testvector(array);
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it;
    for(it=p->begin(); it != p->end(); ++ it)
    {
        printf("%d ", *it);
    }
    return 0;
}

std::vector<int> *testvector(std::vector<int> array) 
{
    return &array;
}
```

Above is my test code; what is wrong that it returned 0 0 3 5 instead of 1 2 3 5

Comment: You are returning a reference to a temporary value. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: The array in `testvector` is a copy of the array you passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `std::vector<int> *testvector(std::vector<int> array)` carefully. This is taking a *deep copy* of the input parameter `array`.

The returned pointer will be *dangling* once `array` is out of scope. The behaviour on dereferencing that pointer will be *undefined*. That's why your program is behaving oddly.

Interestingly, if you had written `std::vector<int>& array` as the parameter (i.e. passed by *reference*) then this would have worked, since you would be returning a pointer to the vector defined in `main`! This code would be *extremely* brittle though.

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
std::vector<int> *testvector(std::vector<int> array)
```

should be replaced with:

```
std::vector<int> *testvector(std::vector<int>& array)
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/5xqp)

However, this is not a real solution since there is no point from your example. I think you have an X problem and you are just posting the Y one. if you post your real problem, it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
std::vector<int> *testvector(std::vector<int> array)
```

to

```
std::vector<int> *testvector(std::vector<int>& array) // Note the &
```

Otherwise the array is copied to a local variable, which is destroyed at the end of `testvector()` which invalidates the returned pointer.